# Why is my SSL Cert/IIS Setup not working correctly?

Tags: security, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, sni

I have 2 domains that are pointed to the same website in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012, domaina.com and domainb.com.

Domaina.com is the primary website and domainb.com is the secondary site.  Right now, domaina.com servers the website and the corresponding SSL Cert, setup as a wildcard for *.domaina.com.  When I browse the site at domainb.com, I get a mismatch error and see that the SSL Cert for domainb.com is the wildcard previously mentioned, *.domaina.com.

I have the bindings setup for domaina.com and www.domaina.com to use the *.domaina.com SSL Cert.  I have the bindings for domainb.com setp for domainb.com and www.domainb.com using the SSL Cert for *.domainb.com.  And all 4 bindings are set to "Require Server Name Identification". I am not seeing why domainb.com is server the incorrect SSL Cert. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please go to HTTP API level to review your current configuration, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html

Comment: Sounds like your client doesn't support SNI.